# How can Siri be instructed to set smart light color temperature automatically?

Tags: siri, homekit

Apple’s “Home” system is capable of setting compatible smart lights, including Philips Hue and others, to a mode which adjusts the color temperature automatically based on brightness and time of day.

[image]

However, while I can easily instruct Siri to set these lights to one of any number of named colors, I don’t know how to tell Siri to enable automatic color temperature mode.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

‘Set *light/room name* to adaptive’

Apple calls the functionality ‘[Adaptive Lighting](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph0a717a8fd/ios#iph79e72e212)’.

Comment: Thanks - I was about to accept this answer, but bizarrely, this doesn’t seem to work. Siri just says that my lights don’t support adaptive lighting! (But they all do — eg as shown in the question’s screen shot).

Comment: I’m going to accept this and consider the failure to be some unknown Apple bug

Comment: I've filed a bug regarding this Siri error and I encourage anyone else with the same question to do so as well: https://www.apple.com/feedback/home-app/
If anyone has *success* using Siri to instigate adaptive lighting, please comment as to your specific setup! Thanks!

Comment: @Alan Sorry to hear you’re having trouble with this. I tested this working for me before posting. All my lights are Philips Hue if that helps / is a difference to your setup.

Comment: Fascinating… I just spent 2 hours with Apple Support and all I got was a suggestion that Siri doesn’t know how to use Adaptive Lighting with Hue bulbs (what I have, as well)! Grr 

Comment: I’m having better luck with this now — as suggested, "Set *x* to adaptive"